# How to deregister a CRON job in AppEngine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cron

I registered a cron job in the google appengine. It runs fine. Since I deleted the whole content of the app, I want this job to not run anymore. I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In Python, to delete all cron jobs, change the cron.yaml file to just contain:

```
cron:
```

In Java, to delete all cron jobs, change the cron.xml file to just contain:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<cronentries/>
```

Comment: How can i do that in PHP?

Comment: The same as in Python

Comment: And run `gcloud app deploy cron.yaml`